# Why do some images fail to display in IE, but not other browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, image

I am encountering a number of images which display in a range of browsers, except for IE6 through IE8. For example, this [image](http://www.dv-light.ru/uploads/images/products/small/istra-1252.jpg), displays fine in browsers other than IE6 through IE8.

You can see this image displaying fine in [Firefox here](http://rghost.ru/4246799.view), but not displaying in [IE8 here](http://rghost.ru/4246829.view).

Any thoughts on the root cause?

Answer (score 5):

That image uses CMYK color (standard for print) instead of RGB (standard for computer screens). Evidently Firefox uses an image library that supports CMYK and Explorer does not.

I really don't recommend ever using CMYK in an image primarily meant to be viewed on a computer, whether or not IE will ever see it — besides spottier support from image libraries, the colorspace just can't represent everything that RGB can.

Comment: This. It applies to all versions of IE since ancient times

Comment: I am shocked that Save For Web did not convert it to RGB, frankly.

Comment: @kindall: I only have the original CS here, but Save for Web *does* convert to RGB for me — it doesn't even give you a choice in the matter. I'll test on CS5 when I get back to civilization, but I would be shocked if that regression actually got through.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a Save For Web in Photoshop, or Save As? You should be using the former. The latter will include various sorts of metadata that Internet Explorer is known to choke on.